# How to add webview in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, native

i am working with the new react native version 0.62 , unfortunately webview is not there anymore , can any one please tell me how to get the webview on the latest react native built.

thanks in advance . 
najath

Answer (score 0):

React native web view is removed from a core and moved to a separate package, you will have to install the package to use webview now.
You can install by

```
npm i react-native-webview

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```

You can read the docs using the below url
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Comment: Thank you, my installed packages got confused. once again , thank you .

Comment: you are welcome, hope you can mark it as the answer :)